# Loading gif not playing after display:block on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gif that i want to play once a form has been submitted (as the process takes awhile to complete). I have a loader html on the page set to display: none.

```
<div id="loading-wrapper">
    <div class="center">
        <div id="loader" class="loader">
            <img id="loadgif" src="img/loading.gif">
        </div>
        div id="loading-text"><h2 style="font-weight:100;" id="theTitle">Rendering</h2></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks submit on the form then "loading-wrapper" is set to display: block. This works fine on desktop, however on mobile (chrome) the gif doesn't play. I have tried dynamically loading the gif after the user submits the form but nothing seems to work

Comment: Could you share the CSS of the `loading-wrapper` element?

Comment: The CSS is Below:

    `#loading-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #D4D5D8;
        z-index: 999;
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }`

On form submit there is a listener that changes display to block. This works fine on everything except mobile. I think this has something to do with the DOM not reloading the image. However when I reload the gif after the display is changed to: block, it still doesn't play.